# Fill table from input from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I have an input, in which a code is entered and filled the table below with information from mysql optenida, the question is that I want every time a code is entered, the table all the data is added (without deleting the previous ). I got the idea to do with Ajax, but do not know where to start. So you see there is an easier way that I'm not seeing (finding on google). I do not like to add this data to a table, I would like it to be temporarily (until the table is confirmed, will be added to the db).

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    table {
        width:100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="input_codigo" placeholder="Codigo del producto" autocomplete="off" autofocus required><br><br>
 </form>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Codigo</b></td>
     <td><b>Descripcion</b></td>
     <td><b>Precio</b></td>
     <td><b>Cantidad</b></td>
     <td><b>Importe</b></td>
   </tr>
     <?php
     session_start();
     error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
     require ("conectar.php");
     $_SESSION["codigo"] = $_POST["input_codigo"];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE codigo = ".$_SESSION['codigo']."";
     $result = $conexion->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          echo "
          <tr>
            <td>".$row["codigo"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["descripcion"]."</td>
            <td>$".$row["venta"]."</td>
            <td><input type='number' name='cantidad' value='1' min='1' max='5'></td>
            <td>$".$row["venta"]."</td>
          </tr>
          ";
         }
     } else {
          echo "";
     }
     $conexion->close();

     ?>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider breaking down this task into manageable sub tasks: 1) Fetch data from the database, 2) Convert the data into an AJAX-friendly format like JSON, 3) Send the data to the client via AJAX, and 4) Convert the AJAX result into an HTML table. Each of these tasks are relatively common, so you will find several hundred code examples on this site and elsewhere to guide you.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Thank you very much right now start searching, I hope someone can help me with some code. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Added jQuery and Ajax request to get the data and then add it to the table.
Changed the PHP a little so that the main HTML is not returned if it is and AJAX request.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    $bAjaxRequest = false;
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $bAjaxRequest = true;
    }
    // if not and ajax request deliver the complete HTML
    if(!$bAjaxRequest) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    table {
        width:100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="index.php" method="post" id="frmQuery" name="frmQuery">
   <input type="text" name="input_codigo" id="input_codigo" placeholder="Codigo del producto" autocomplete="off" autofocus required><br><br>
 </form>
 <table id="tblData" name="tblData">
   <tr>
     <td><b>Codigo</b></td>
     <td><b>Descripcion</b></td>
     <td><b>Precio</b></td>
     <td><b>Cantidad</b></td>
     <td><b>Importe</b></td>
   </tr>
     <?php
    } // end if(!$bAjaxRequest) {
    // we are always going to return the TR's or ""
     require ("conectar.php");
    
     // ALWAYS, BUT ALWAYS VERIFY/VALIDATE USER INPUT!!!
     $_SESSION["codigo"] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["input_codigo"]); // for example
     
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE codigo = ".$_SESSION['codigo']."";
     $result = $conexion->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          echo "
          <tr>
            <td>".$row["codigo"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["descripcion"]."</td>
            <td>$".$row["venta"]."</td>
            <td><input type='number' name='cantidad' value='1' min='1' max='5'></td>
            <td>$".$row["venta"]."</td>
          </tr>
          ";
         }
     } else {
          echo "";
     }
     $conexion->close();

    // if not and ajax request deliver the complete HTML
    if(!$bAjaxRequest) { ?>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function loadData(codigo) {
        $.post( "index.php", { input_codigo: codigo }, function( data ) {
        $("#tblData").append(data);
        });
 }
 
    $(function() {
    // jQuery POST are never cached, but if you change to GET you'll need this next line
    //$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });
    
    $("#frmQuery").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadData($("#input_codigo").val());
    }); 
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    }
?>
```